# A panel to change 3d object properties when right click on it (Unity)

Tags: unity, gui

I'm building a UI system to edit selected 3D objects. I have spheres on the screen and I want to be able to edit their proprieties (radius for example). In order to do that I want the user to be able to click on a sphere and then it show a panel next to the object. When the user changes slider value the radius of the sphere which as been clicked on change. Using the new unity event system, I think it's easy to achieve, but I'm a new to unity and even if I know the basic I don't know how to organize this properly.

At the end my goal would be to select multiple sphere, right click and edit the radius to all selected spheres. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPPps.jpg Any tips on how to do that ? Sorry for my poor english. Thanks

Comment: For selection you should use ray casts (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CameraRays.html), this will give you the selected game object, after that making the UI should be simple. Btw you should consider asking Unity related questions over at: http://answers.unity3d.com/

Answer (score 1):

you should ray casts for selecting sphere game object, then use attached script to on value change in slider game object you can use this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SelectSphere : MonoBehaviour {
public  GameObject selectedSphere;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) 
            selectedSphere=hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
    }
    public void ChangeRadiusOfSphere()
    {
        if(selectedSphere!=null)
        {
            float sildervalue=GameObject.Find("Slider").GetComponent<Slider>().value;
            if(sildervalue!=0)
                selectedSphere.transform.localScale=new Vector3 (sildervalue*2f,sildervalue*2f,sildervalue*2f);
        }
    }
}
```